# Which version of Infinispan runs on Jboss AS 5.1.0 GA?

Tags: caching, jboss, jboss5.x, infinispan

As per [this post](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Infinispan+as+Hibernate+2nd-Level+Cache+in+JBoss+AS+5.x) Infinispan 4.x can be run on Jboss AS 5.1.0 GA.

`1.` So, is that it? Can't we run higher versions of Infinispan on Jboss AS 5.1.0 GA?

`2.` Some bug fixes would have been done on Infinispan 4.x and upgraded to higher versions. So, if I use Infinispan 4.x what all bugs I could face?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can run any version you like, but you'll have to isolate the classes to avoid conflicting with the ones included in the AS. Of course you can't replace the clustering technology in AS5 with it: you can use it exclusively with your own applications. If you intend to use it with Hibernate make sure you pick an Hibernate version compatible with the Infinispan version you choose: consequentially you might need to bundle a custom Hibernate version as well, and isolate from the older version provided in AS5. Generally, the Infinispan team does not consider AS5 support a goal and we're not actively testing for this.
2. Hard to tell which issues could affect you not knowing what you plan to use it for. All issues are tracked in the open as well so feel free to check: [Infinispan changelog](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3achangelog-panel&allVersions=true) or ask for more advice on the [Infinispan forums](https://community.jboss.org/en/infinispan?view=discussions).

Comment: Thanks. For 1st question, do you conclude that in 'theory' one can run any version of Infinispan on Jboss AS 5.x but one cannot assure practically what problems one might face? This [post](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Infinispan+as+Hibernate+2nd-Level+Cache+in+JBoss+AS+5.x) talks about Infinispan 4.x + Jboss 5.x configuration. [This](http://infinispan.blogspot.in/) tells that Infinispan 5.2.0 is a stable release with many bug fixes. So, is there any post/link which talks about configuring Infinispan 5.2.0 with Jboss 5.x?

Comment: I agree: in theory any version will work, as long as you isolate the classes, but nothing is being tested by the core team. The post you are referring to having deployed it on AS5 are made by contributors or power users. I'm not aware of more posts talking about the 5.2 + AS5 combination, and I wouldn't encourage them as people should move to EAP6: lots of good reasons to update, including a perfect class isolation which means you'll never have such problems even in far future.